# How to access the value of a TextView that is inside an inflated layout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

I need to be able to access the double in the textview 'quota' in order to do some maths with it.  Problem is I'm getting an error on the line where it is supposed to get the value.  This may be because the textview is within an inflated layout, I'm not sure.

I've tried using the name set in my adaptor, which I thought might be the way to access it, but no luck.

**Finding the textview in the main class, calling it quota**

```
quota = findViewById(R.id.textView_dailyData_BricksQuota);
```

**Finding the textview in the adapter class, calling it dataBricksQuota, tried calling this in the main class instead but doesn't work**

```
TextView dataBricksQuota = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_dailyData_BricksQuota); 

dataBricksQuota.setText(String.valueOf(project.getBricksQuota()));
```

**Problem occurs on line one of this if statement, where I try to get the value of the textview in the main class**

```
if (projectDay >= 2) {

    String currentBrickQuota = quota.getText().toString();

    double currentBrickQuotaDouble = Double.parseDouble(currentBrickQuota);

    double averageBrickRunningQuota = ((2 * currentBrickQuotaDouble + averageBricksNDatabase) / projectDay);
    String sql = "UPDATE activeProjectsTable SET averageBricks = ? WHERE ProjectId = (SELECT MAX(ProjectId) FROM activeProjectsTable)";
    AusWideDatabase.execSQL(sql, new Double[] {
        averageBrickRunningQuota
    });
}
```

I would have thought that it would simply take the value of the textview so it can be used in the equation, however when I run the if statement, there's an error.

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27774) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.auswide.auswideapp.dailyData.LoadEodChecklist(dailyData.java:145)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7333) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14160) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7299) 
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27774) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: make sure the id is exists in the inflated layout.

Comment: The variable quota is not taking proper reference , so check if textView_dailyData_BricksQuota is present in the corresponding layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it, if you pass context of your main class. Code will be as follow

```
TextView textView = ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.yourTextView); // -> context must be context of your main class
textView.setText("Hello world"); // -> textView variable is not null, so it will assign text to textView
```

Another way would be inflating whole layout, but I don't find it useful in this case.

Comment: Cheers, that worked.  I was wondering if had something to do with the context. And passing it does make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but it just dawned on me that this is simply a visual aid for the user.  I set up a global variable for the quota and modified it accordingly when the equation was run, then simply called the variable again to replace what it says on the textview.